# how to associate an ip with a name?

Tags: ip, voip, asterisk, sip

I have installed an asterisk on my private network(so it s behind a router ). Is there anu way to set the asterisk on a public ip though it's installed in a server with private ip? As Ive read it ispossible using externip and externhost.

My second question is: Can I set a specific name over the domain? I mean can I associate ip:xxx.xxx.xxx.xx with my_domain? How to set this on asterisk?

I am new to this stuff. need some help! appreciate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has more to do with your router than asterisk.
You want to set up forwarding rules on your router for specific ports from the router to the machine running asterisk. The router will forward the socket connections from the router to asterisk and asterisk won't know it isn't facing the internet directly.
I don't know the asterisk ports, but I'm sure they're listed in a config file somewhere.
Alternatively, and I don't recommend this, you can set up again in the router config, the machine running asterisk to be the DMZ, which means basically any inbound connections  to your router from the internet go to the machine you designate as DMZ. If you have lots of services to forward this is easier than setting up rules, but just for one thing like asterisk, you're better up just setting up forwarding rules for the specific ports you need.

Comment: thX Stu for your answers. You did light me up! Appreciate a lot! I did post a new question. If you have any solutions to it please teach me! appreciate

Answer (score 0):

As for setting up a DNS name to point to your ip address, you need a DNS provider. Your registraar (godaddy, network solutions, etc) probably sells this service for a few bucks a year.